# Replace text in the line before pattern

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I have a text like this

```
5834589
  MDL-BLABLABLA1
bla-bla2
bla-bla3
bla-bla4
bla-bla5
```

I want to replace 5834589 (number) in the line *before* line with the pattern MDL to EXAMPLE-RIVER-5834589 (Just add EXAMPLE-RIVER-).

Any suggestions with sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/^.*\n.*MDL/EXAMPLE-RIVER-&/;P;D' file
```